# MVC duplicating verification

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm fairly new to MVC, having issues with validation.  Have an a model which includes an Enumerable List of players.  The model also includes an instance of a player and team.  In the view I am using a foreach statement to display the players in a table so the details can be edited.  In the foreach I have a partial view to handle an iteration of the model.Players list.  The form shows all the iterations fine and allows the user to change the values. If a certain value is empty then it will fail validation back to the view.  For some reason instead of it showing the other iterations with there values and the failed one with the warning in it, the result duplicates the iteration with the failed validation for the count of items in the enumeration.

I've followed the code through and it shows as the correct data being entered for each iteration even when there is a validation failure but it still displays each iteration as the failed iteration when resolved to the browser.

Model

```
public class Players
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int PlayerNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }
    public int Comp { get; set; }
    //Not included all the values rest are int or string
}
```

View

```
     @model TeamPlayersModel
     @foreach (var CurrentPlayer in Model.Players)
     {
        @Html.Partial("_PartialViewForEditPlayer", CurrentPlayer)
     }
```

Partial View

```
    @model Players

    @using (Html.BeginForm("EditPlayer", "Campaign", FormMethod.Post, new { name = Model.Id, id = Model.Id }))
    {
        {
    <tr>
        <td><div class="text-box">@Html.EditorFor(p => p.PlayerNumber)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.PlayerNumber)</div></td>

        <td><div class="text-box">@Html.EditorFor(p => p.PlayerName, new { style = "width:100px" })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.PlayerName)</div></td>

    @Html.HiddenFor(p => p.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(p => p.TeamId)

    <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
</td>
    </tr>
    }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure this is the issue, but are you intending to create a form for every row in the table?  Because the BeginForm is inside the partial view which is inside  a loop, you are creating a new form for each row.

Comment: It is creating a new form for each row, allowing the changes to just that row to be submitted for changes

Comment: What you doing makes no sense. You can only ever submit one form at a time. Apart from all the invalid html because of duplicate `id` attributes, you creating duplicate `name` attributes so validation errors can never be matched up with the correct element (and you would never be able to return the view from the controller method anyway)

Comment: Either have one form and generate the collection correctly using a `for` loop or custom `EditorTemplate` so that you can edit any or all items in the collection and post back the collection, or have links that take you to a page that edits a single item in your collection.

Answer (score 0):

Check the source of the page.  Your 'data-valmsg-for' will most likely have the same values.  So when there is an issue it will reveal text on each of these.

It look like what you want is an AJAX style form.  This should help you get started.

http://eliot-jones.com/2014/09/mvc-ajax